# Why is there no (Debian) init.d script for usbipd? Should I write my own?

Tags: networking, usb, daemon, init.d, kernel-modules

I just installed the usbip package on my Debian Wheezy (7.1) . For some reason, it comes without an init.d script.

- Why is there no init.d script for it?
- Should I roll out my own? Or am I doing something wrong?
- What's the best way to ensure the relevant kernel modules are loaded? `modprobe` them in the init script? Put their names in `/etc/modules`?

Comment: You should ask the packager. Though if I had to guess, it's probably because there's absolutely no security.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: 1. Do other distributions have an init script for it? 2. I can't believe that's the reason. If I install a telnet server, won't I get an init script for it?